# How to open the Graphical Console of a QEMU/KVM VM with virsh?

Tags: 20.04, bash, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm teaching mysel KVM/QEMU and working with the virt-install and virsh commands. the one thing I can't figure out how to do is launch the graphical console from the virsh shell. is this possible?

Specifically, when I start a domain with something like `virsh start <MachineName>` I dont seem to be able to find a command that will let me launch the graphical window that displays the VM screen / launch the graphical console?

Answer (score 0):

AH! Looks like I found the answer in this [AU StackExchange Article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803888/virt-manager-launcher-action-to-directly-start-and-open-a-specific-vm)

You do not use the virsh console, you use the virt-manager (typically installed with KVM/QEMU anyways). The Command is:

virt-manager --connect qemu:///system --show-domain-console < VMNAME >

so to break that down, you're telling virt-manager to connect to the hypervisor running on local host and then asking for the domain console of a particular vm name.

Comment: `virsh console` is like the serial console of that system, while the suggestion as well as `virt-viewer` or `spicy` can connect to the exposed graphical output.